# How to grab an 'img' title attribute and place it into a h2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the plugin described in [Create a Thumbnail with Fading Caption Using jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/844/create-a-thumbnail-with-fading-caption-using-jquery), but I would like my caption to be an `h2` and text grabbed from the `img` attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following that plugin code, make the HTML like this instead of the plugin example:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="link">
        <img src="link img" title="your title" width="125" height="125"/>
        <div class="caption">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then this is the updated jQuery you need, with comments to explain:

```
 $(function() {
     // let's set a variable as our img attr title
     var title = $("img").attr('title');

     var move = -15;

     //zoom percentage, 1.2 =120%
     var zoom = 1.2;

     //On mouse over those thumbnail
     $('.item').hover(function() {
         //Grab title from title attr
          $("h2").hide().append(title).fadeIn('slow');

         //Set the width and height according to the zoom percentage
         width = $('.item').width() * zoom;
         height = $('.item').height() * zoom;

         //Move and zoom the image
         $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'width':width, 'height':height, 'top':move, 'left':move}, {duration:200});

         //Display the caption
         $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(200);
     },
     function() {
         //Remove title
         $("h2").empty();

         //Reset the image
         $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'width':$('.item').width(), 'height':$('.item').height(), 'top':'0', 'left':'0'}, {duration:100});

         //Hide the caption
         $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
     });
 });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u2HxY/40/

Answer (score 1):

Grab the `alt` attribute and put it in the caption HTML.

```
 $('#captionID').html($('#imageID').attr('alt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$('#imgSelector').attr('title')
```

or

```
$('#imgSelector').attr('alt')
```